# Mongo ODM Doctrine with Composer - Aggregation builder

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, composer-php

I would like to use Aggregation builder from Mongo ODM in my project. In my composer.json file I set the latest version of Mongo ODM (on docs.doctrine-project they say that it's 1.1.4).
Then I'm installing all the packages, and I cannot see the Aggregation Builder in Mongo ODM folder.
Could someone help me how to add it to my project? Thank you!

Comment: You can find the Aggregation Builder(`Builder.php`) in `vendor/Doctrine/ODM/MongoDB/Aggregation/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aggregation Builder is available only in in the `master` branch until it is officially released with version 1.2. Until that happens I'd suggest using `dev-master` and switch again to proper version as soon as possible.